# Как подключить jQuery к проекту?

Tags: jquery, jsp, java

Сорри за глупый вопрос, но как правильно подключить jQuery к проекту? Работаю в Eclipse (for Weblogic). Просто кинуть файлы *.js в папку WebContent и потом вызвать в JSP в хеде..не получилось =\

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=" <с:url value='jquery-1.6.1.js'/>"></script>
```

Пробовал ещё добавлять в настройках проекта, в build path тоже не вышло...

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src='../jquery-1.6.1.js'/>
ну не знаю, не должно быть проблем, укажи путь конкретнее к jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

есть ещё один вариант, хотя предыдущие советы тоже хороши!

1. можно подключить библиотеку с сайта производителя `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js` - ссылка для полной версии (можно подгрузить сжатую версию)
2. подключить библиотеку с репозитория Google: `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js`

ну а напоследок могу Вам добавить ещё немного информации. создавать абсолютные ссылки в Windows не совсем благодарное дело. например, путь, который Вы указали к файлу с библиотекой будет по-разному пониматься в *nix-системах и системых Windows (в Windows-путях обратный слэш используется).
поэтому, если нет доступа в инет, рядом с главной страницей проекта (страницы, к которой Вы подключаете библиотеку) создайте папочку scripts к примеру (или js, всё по-разному делают) положите туда исходный файл библиотеки и со страницы сошлитесь scripts/jquery-1.7.js (или js/jquery-1.7.js)....относительные пути не вызывают проблем.

Comment: спасибо за совет! завтра попробую, потом отпишусь

Comment: подключил эту  http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.js -  всё заработало =)

Answer (score 0):

`<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>`
, вместо ".." укажите ваш путь к папке со скриптом от корня.

Comment: вот к примеру пишу так:
<pre><code>
<head>
        <title>jQuery Test Project</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/java_libs/jquery/lib/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("h1").click(function(){
          $(this).addClass("blue");
             });
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            .blue { color: blue; }
        </style>
    </head>
</pre></code>  
И ничего....

Comment: Из этого <code>src="C:/java_libs/jquery/lib/jquery-1.6.1.js"</code> уберите <code>C:/java_libs</code> и вообще мне тогда не понятно где у вас скрипт лежит. Создайте в проекте папку js и киньте в нее скрипт, а не подсоединяйте неизвестно откуда.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, если хотите позаморачиваться, то можно написать

`<html:script env="javascript" src='js/jquery.min.js' />`

но проще сделать просто тегом скрипт