# http status 415 spring rest json

Tags: ajax, json, spring, spring-mvc, rest

Делаю простое Rest приложение, и столкнулся с проблемой при переводе данных в json формат. При попытке создать пользователя вылазит ошибка "http status 415". Хочу получать данные о пользователе в JSON-формате и сохранять их в БД. Подскажите, как исправить ошибку. Буду благодарен за помощь, если не хватает информации - пишите, что еще необходимо, буду добавлять.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
User Controller

```
@RestController
public class UserControllerImpl implements UserController {

private UserRepository repository;

public UserControllerImpl() {
}

@Autowired
public UserControllerImpl(UserRepository repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String welcomeFile() {
    return "index";
}


@RequestMapping(value = "addUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@Override
public String addUser(ModelMap model) {
    return "addUser";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"application/json"}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Override
public @ResponseBody String addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
    this.repository.createUser(user);
    return "OK";
}
```

}

JSP страница добавления пользователя

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: Ar4er
  Date: 10.06.16
  Time: 19:23
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add User</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#registerUserSubmit").click(function () {
            var user = {
                firstName: $("#firstName").val(),
                lastName: $("#lastName").val(),
                userName: $("#userName").val(),
                plainTextPassword: $("#plainTextPassword").val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                url: "addUser",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(user),
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    location.reload();
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    alert('A user with the given username already exists ' + status + ". " + errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<form method="post" action="addUser" commandName="user">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="plainTextPassword" id="plainTextPassword" value=""/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="registerUserSubmit" value="Registration"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

User class

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "rest_users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @NotNull
    private int id;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "firstName")
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "lastName")
    @NotNull
    private String lastName;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "userName")
    @NotNull
    private String userName;

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "plainTextPassword")
    @Length(min = 5)
    @NotNull
    private String plainTextPassword;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String firstName, String lastName, String userName, String plainTextPassword) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.plainTextPassword = plainTextPassword;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPlainTextPassword() {
        return plainTextPassword;
    }

    public void setPlainTextPassword(String plainTextPassword) {
        this.plainTextPassword = plainTextPassword;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        User user = (User) o;

        if (id != user.id) return false;
        if (firstName != null ? !firstName.equals(user.firstName) : user.firstName != null) return false;
        if (lastName != null ? !lastName.equals(user.lastName) : user.lastName != null) return false;
        if (userName != null ? !userName.equals(user.userName) : user.userName != null) return false;
        return plainTextPassword != null ? plainTextPassword.equals(user.plainTextPassword) : user.plainTextPassword == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + (firstName != null ? firstName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (lastName != null ? lastName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (userName != null ? userName.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (plainTextPassword != null ? plainTextPassword.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

User Repository

```
    @Repository
@Transactional
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public UserRepositoryImpl() {
    }

    @Override
    public User createUser(User user) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.save(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>CRUD</groupId>
    <artifactId>CRUD</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Simple REST</name>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.0.3.Final</hibernate.version>
        <!--DB-->
        <postgresql.version>9.4.1211</postgresql.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--DataBase-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.2-1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>project</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application-contxt.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties" system-properties-mode="ENVIRONMENT"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.temaprof.app.repository"/>


    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.databaseurl}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="prefixJson" value="false"/>
        <property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="application/json"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan">
            <array>
                <value>com.temaprof.app.model</value>
            </array>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <value>hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: посмотрите, что у вас пишет в лог сервера.

Comment: Аннотацию @Basic можно опускать. Зачем нужно проверять заголовок `Accept` и использовать параметр `produces`?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman лог выдает следующее: org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerEx‌​ceptionResolver.logE‌​xception Handler execution resulted in exception: Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' not supported

Comment: @Alex78191 Basic, Accept и produces убрал. Добавил зависимости Jackson и Jackson-databind. Всё еще не работает.

Comment: @ArtemVorov Что за ерунда? У тебя же Content-Type не `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Зачем использовать JSON, если можно использовать [`$("#idForm").serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) для urlencoded https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960586/4854931

Comment: @Alex78191 Я только начал разбираться с JSON, пока устраивает то, что всё заработало, т.к. до завтра необходимо выполнить тестовое задание.

Comment: @ArtemVorov я же сказал, что ты json не используешь в итоге, у тебя страница перезагружается.

Comment: @Alex78191 что тогда необходимо сделать, что бы заработал JSON?

Comment: Я же написал https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/677819/http-status-415-spring-rest-json?noredirect=1#comment991752_677941

Comment: @Alex78191 Последний глупый вопрос - куда я должен вставить эту строку  event.preventDefault() ?

Comment: Этот пример вам непонятен? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960240/jquery-ajax-submit-form/6960586#6960586 Также это событие можно использовать вообще вместо `$("#registerUserSubmit").click`

Comment: Про убрать `type=submit` не думали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы использовать аннтотации `@RequestBody`/`@ResponseBody` [нужно добавить](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.html) тег `<mvc:annotation-driven />` в `dispatcher-servlet.xml`. Если не добавить тег, то это может вызывать HTTP ошибку `415 Unsupported Media Type`

> The server refused this request because the request entity
>   is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the
>   requested method

Лог tomcat

> org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerEx‌​ceptionResolver.logE‌​xception
>   Handler execution resulted in exception: Content type
>   'application/json' not supported

---

Вам нужно будет добавить `jackson` и `jackson-databind` в classpath. Spring будет использовать его [`MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/json/MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter.html).

Также в конечном итоге AJAX не использует потому что не написано [`event.preventDefault()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960586/4854931) для события `submit`. 
Иначе можно `type="submit"` не писать.

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Избегать выполнения стандартной отправки формы.
});
```

Событие submit относится к форме, а не кнопке.

Чтобы использовать библиотеку jQuery (методы `$()`), ее нужно сначала подключить –  [Как подключить jQuery к проекту?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/54806/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-jquery-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83) .

Answer (score -1):

Ответ нашел здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4339207/http-post-with-request-content-type-form-not-working-in-spring-mvc-3, надо было вместо @RequestBody использовать @ModelAttribute.

Comment: Лайк, если считаешь, что автор не использует ajax потому что не написал [`event.preventDefault()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6960586/4854931) для события submit. Мог бы иначе `type="submit"`не писать.

Comment: То, как ты сделал сейчас, означает, что можно вообще аннотацию не использовать.